# is there an easy way or photoshop plugin to distribute words in evenly spaced formation

Tags: adobe-photoshop, plugin

I try to do it mostly with words but sometimes have to do it with other things too. How do you equally space out things automatically, I Know how to evenly distribute from **the center** of every **layer/object** but not how to have even actual space between those to objects.

This is really not a problem when all the things are of the same width (or height) but as you know words are hardly ever that. So what i do is is make a rectangle of size that i want space to be empty and once done typing i manually drag out that box to the end of the first word, then adjust the 2nd one decrease/increase the space to match the edges of the rectangle and so on for the texts after 2nd..like 3rd,4th...Usually it's Home, About, Products, Contact, etc...

[image]

Comment: This is why Fireworks is superior for web design and interface design. It was built for that purpose. Photoslop was built for photo editing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't.**

**Photoshop offers no "distribute spacing" options out of the box.**

The only way I know to do this in Photoshop is via scripting. You can check out the [distribute scripts from Trevor Morris here](http://morris-photographics.com/photoshop/scripts/index.html).

Comment: i just installed it and it works. But keep the answers coming.

Comment: There are no other answers unless you want to manually measure space between object and move things yourself or use a different application.

Answer (score 0):

Um... I'm a bit confused cause

> how to have even actual space between those words
>
> So what i do is is make a rectangle of size that i want space to be empty and once done typing i manually drag out that box to the end of the first word, then adjust the 2nd one decrease/increase the space to match the edges of the rectangle and so on for the texts after 2nd..like 3rd,4th...Usually it's Home, About, Products, Contact, etc...

- Text tool
- Click and drag so it creates a text box
- Change paragraph style to *Justify All*
- Type in `Home About Products Contact`

Think I must be missing something cause while I don't know Muhammad or Yawn, I do know Scott would know this.

Comment: This is little inconvinient. As it would lock the all in one. I would like home text to be sepearte so this way i can't style `home` separately with ease. Also this only works for text what about something else with different widths... how would i distribute space evenly and not evenly from their center.

Comment: Take a look at question..

Comment: Ya I figured that was it but your question does, and still says, "distribute words in evenly spaced formation." If you're asking about all objects then no, this would not be a solution.