# Distribute tool not working properly

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, alignment

Ok, I tried searching for this but did not find anything relevant. I am facing a weird issue in Photoshop. When using the Distribute Tool, the elements align in a weird manner.

Here is an example -

I have made 5 identical rectangles on top of each other.

[image]

Now, I moved the top layer away from the stack and applied horizontal and vertical distribution on the stack.

[image]

As you can see, the manner in which the shapes distribute themselves is kinda bizarre.

In an ideal situation, I expect the shapes to be distributed evenly between the top layer and the bottom layer. Here, the distribution is way off.

Does anyone have any clue as to what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop's distribution... well... sucks much of the time.

What is happening is the shapes are being distributed based upon **centers**. And the *centers* **are** distributed correctly. Photoshop doesn't see the "edges" of the shapes when distributing. It *only* sees the center.

What you appear to *want* is **distribute spacing** which Photoshop, after 20+ years of development, still *can  not do*.

See this question to address distributing spaces in Photoshop:
[How to distribute an equal amount of space between each object in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/how-to-distribute-an-equal-amount-of-space-between-each-object-in-photoshop)

Beyond that, it takes *manual* alignment to distribute objects based upon spacing around them or their outer dimensions.

Comment: Hope they fix it! Pretty lame on Adobe's part if you ask me.I know the interface is different, but Illustrator does a much better job in distributing objects.

Comment: I would not hold your breath waiting on Adobe here. People have been complaining about this since Photoshop 5.5, more than 10 years ago

Comment: For a software giant, they sure have more than a few things to catch up on. Some days ago, I was looking for the JS reference for Photoshop Scripting but it has also not been updated.

Comment: They are a giant.. and move at the speed of a giant. And ignore many small things like a giant. And crush smaller things in their path like a giant. And take what is unreasonable like a giant. And consider people largely unimportant like a giant.`:)`

Comment: Haha !! True !!